# Set specific form control (part of a larger form group) as required conditionally only if another specific form control in that form group has value

Tags: angular, forms, validation, ionic-framework

I have seen many other questions with SIMILAR scenarios to this one, but not quite what I was looking for.

I have a form group being created in my typescript file with a whole bunch of form controls (id, firstName, lastName, email, etc. etc.). Some controls have Validators.required set and some do not.

I ran into the scenario (which I'm sure is fairly common) where I only want one specific form control in this group to be set as required ONLY IF one of the other controls in the group has a value (the other control is NOT required).

What is the best practice for handling this?

Lets just say for example I have the following method for setting up the form group...

```
private initFormClient(): FormGroup {
    let clientGroup = this.fb.group({
        id: [client.id], //hidden
        firstName: [client.firstName, Validators.required],
        lastName: [client.lastName, Validators.required],
        email: [client.email, Validators.required]),
        phone: [client.phone],
        birthday: [moment(client.birthday).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), Validators.required],
        enrollmentDate: [moment(this.workingEnrollment.enrollmentDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'), Validators.required],
        dischargeDate: [this.workingEnrollment.dischargeDate ?moment(this.workingEnrollment.dischargeDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined],
        treatmentLevelDate: [this.workingEnrollment.treatmentLevelDate ? moment(this.workingEnrollment.treatmentLevelDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD') : undefined],
        treatmentLevelId: 
        profileImageUri: [client.profileImageUri],
        profileImageFile: [''],
    });
    return clientGroup;
}
```

I want to set the treatmentLevelDate control as required only if the treatmentLevelId has value (chosen by the user). I don't want to add a global validator to the group unless that is necessary. I'd rather just learn how to set up a custom validator for an individual control if possible. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to set validators dynamically using [`setValidators()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setvalidators) function:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.form = this.initFormClient();

  this.form.get('firstName').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    if ((val || '').split(' ').filter(Boolean).length > 1) {
      this.form.get('lastName').clearValidators();
    }
    else {
      this.form.get('lastName').setValidators(Validators.required);      
    }
    this.form.get('lastName').updateValueAndValidity();
  });
}
```

In this example *Last Name* field will be required only if the *First Name* field contains less than 2 words. If *First Name* field contains more than 1 word, *Last Name* field will NOT be required.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rnjke?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)